# How to modify an ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, action, actionevent

I have a class that receives an Actionevent. I want to modify this event and add some objects to it (if that is possible). Kinda like how you do with Intents in Android. Is this possible or not?

To add some background:

The first class receives an actionEvent when a button is clicked, but I want this class to add a string value to the actionEvent and dispatch the event to another class acting as an actionlistener for this class. Is this possible or not? Would the dispatched event trigger an actionPerformed event?

Comment: Intents benefit from the presence of the extras bundle, which effectively gives you a place to store custom data. ActionEvent has no such provisions, so unless you want to extend ActionEvent, you're going to have to come up with a different mechanism for sending custom data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by merging both classes into one which made it a lot easier by simply setting a variable and call a function to accomplish what I wanted. The other solution would have been to create a custom editable event and make both classes receivers of this event, but this is an assignment and I didn't have time to do that